# I got Mongoose-Auth to work, but how do I do some custom stuff to it?

Tags: javascript, authentication, mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I followed instructions on Mongoose-auth and got the system working on my node.js: https://github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-auth

```
facebook: {
          everyauth: {
              myHostname: 'http://localhost:3000'
            , appId: 'YOUR APP ID HERE'
            , appSecret: 'YOUR APP SECRET HERE'
            , redirectPath: '/home'
          }
        }
```

So, I did this with Mongoose-auth, and I was able to connect through Facebook. What I want is to **"do something"** after Facebook hits me back.  Right now, it just redirects me to "home", and logs the user in.  I want to do something before it redirects me to home. How can I do taht?

In EveryAuth, I did it using this:

```
.findOrCreateUser( function (session, accessToken, fbUserMetadata) {
    // find or create user logic goes here
  })
```

But I'm guessing that's not available in mongoose-auth....since that's not in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

Everything you have access to with `everyauth` is available to `mongoose-auth`. Just convert the chained method you would use in `everyauth` from the method call into a key-value in the everyauth key in your `mongoose-auth` configuration:

```
facebook: {
  everyauth: {
      myHostname: 'http://localhost:3000'
    , appId: 'YOUR APP ID HERE'
    , appSecret: 'YOUR APP SECRET HERE'
    , redirectPath: '/home'
    , findOrCreateUser: function (session, accessToken, fbUserMetadata) {
      }
  }
}
```